# How to avoid scroll bar in all browsers while a jQuery Dialog box is showing?

Tags: jquery

I have a page where when we click a button a Jquery dialog box is called using JQuery. But when it is shown the Window scroll bar is shown in all browsers. How can we avoid this?
Can we avoid this uising JQuery? Or is it is better to fix by CSS?.

Comment: Save your soul and share some code or a live example. How do you expect people to help you when all they have to go on is "there's a scroll bar, how can we fix it?". Going on nothing, make the dialog small enough to fit in the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

css

```
.hidescrolls {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

JQ

```
...click(function (){
   // show dialog();
   $('body,html').addClass('hidescrolls');
});
```

make sure you use the `$('body,html').removeClass('hidescrolls');` on dialog close/hide

Comment: thanks buddy, its working in fine in Firefox, and IE7 but problem still comes in IE8.

Comment: it should be cross browser, make sure you clear any cache on ie8 just incase the css is cached

Answer (score 1):

Just set the overflow on the body tag to hidden, should do the trick:

```
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/xYatB/1/